# Using brave browser to debug flutter web app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-debug, flutter-devtools

I just started-off with `flutter web` and **I want to use brave browser** to debug my flutter apps not chrome or edge.

When I use `flutter devices` command, it gives the following result.

```
No devices detected.

Run "flutter emulators" to list and start any available device emulators.
```

I'm using brave by using the link provided by web-server  and it does not support `hot reload`.

So, how to configure browsers other than chrome or edge with flutter web for complete functionality.

Comment: this [blog post](https://blog.albertobonacina.com/flutter-and-brave-test-your-web-apps-on-your-favorite-browser?guid=none&deviceId=886ec8ea-ed11-48a3-ac6b-6ea478d46d71) worked for me. Make sure you restart vs code(if you are developing with this) once you set the environment variable

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found [this](https://blog.albertobonacina.com/flutter-and-brave-test-your-web-apps-on-your-favorite-browser):

> All you have to do, based on your Linux operating system (for Windows
> and macOS the process is similar), is to modify your .bashrc file and
> insert this line:
>
> ```
> #Put your Brave installation location here
> export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/opt/brave.com/brave/brave-browser"
> ```

For MacOs,

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser"
```

Comment: You are right, for people that are still stuck on this, please note that `/Applications/Brave\ Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave\ Browser` is not valid due to backslashes `\\`, so do not forget to remove them.

Comment: How to do this for windows? I did set CHROME_EXECUTABLE="path\brave.exe" but it says that this is not an executable

Comment: For MacOs users, if you are using zsh you need to add the `export` to `.zshrc` (instead of `.bashrc`)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `flutter run -d web-server` to run your app **like a server**.
This means that you can just enter the URL on **any browser** of your choice to access your Flutter app !

Drawbacks:

- Hot Restart/Reload from the terminal is not possible. You must refresh the page on your browser instead.

Advantages:

- You can use any browser for developing flutter apps.
- You can even use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to forward your port to a HTTPS URL, and access your flutter app from anywhere (your phone, your desktop , someone else's device etc.)

PS: Credits to the Issue [#77229](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77229) for helping me find this solution. I am aware that this workaround has already been suggested on this thread.
I just wanted to put out a simpler answer for the general viewer.

Answer (score 3):

I've been diving in the same issue, it's known Brave it's Chromium-based, this will help u https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77229

Comment: I tried using `flutter run -d web-server` but it didn't not support `hot restart` in my case, I had to refresh the browser to see my changes.