# Flutter Web browser emulator not appearing as option in VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I set the CHROME_EXECUTABLE environment variable:

```
(base) Joels-MBP:~ jcastro2$ echo $CHROME_EXECUTABLE
/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser

(base) Joels-MBP:~ jcastro2$ ls /Applications/Brave\ Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave\ Browser 
/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser

(base) Joels-MBP:~ jcastro2$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

(base) Joels-MBP:~ jcastro2$ flutter devices
2 connected devices:

macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-x64
Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Brave Browser 111.1.49.120

(base) Joels-MBP:corbu jcastro2$ flutter run -d chrome
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             19.6s
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:53120/Hampj1DMeys=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53120/Hampj1DMeys=/ws

 Running with sound null safety 

  To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".

An Observatory debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:53120/Hampj1DMeys=
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Programmatic
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:53120/Hampj1DMeys=
```

**Available emulators:**
[image: Available emulators]

Why is the Brave browser not showing up even though `flutter doctor` says that everything is ok with the Chrome configuration?

Comment: can you check `flutter device`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes, I did. see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround for your issue is mentioned here
[Brave Browser Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70279343/6786113)

run your app like a server

```
  flutter run -d web-server
```

http://localhost:5353

then use the generated link and open it in any browser.

Comment: yes, this works, however I was not looking for a workaround, I wanted a direct solution to my question. Although your solution is a workaround, it is ultimately not what I was looking for. Thanks for your answer, but I can't afford to pay 50 reputation for this lol

Comment: No Problem I tried the same for my project but Brave Browser not showing in list

Comment: Looks like I have to award the bounty to someone. Here you go mate, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specifically add a web target for this project via `flutter create --platforms web`?

Without this, the flutter plugin of Visual Studio Code thinks you do not intend to run this app on a browser. After adding the web target, your selected Chrome_Executable (chrome in my case) will show up in the UI.

Before:
[image: Browser not listed in the menu]

After:
[image: Browser listed in the menu]

Comment: if I have Chrome preinstalled, it appears in the list of available devices. But I don't want Chrome, I want Brave.