# How can I integrate Brave browser into Flutter devices for testing?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to add brave browser in flutter devices?

i'm using windows

C:\flutter_project>flutter devices

3 connected devices:

Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.1817]

Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.127

Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 113.0.1774.50

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using brave browser to debug flutter web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598551/using-brave-browser-to-debug-flutter-web-app)